Expanding quantities that contain vectors
If we have $|\vec x - \vec R_{\vec n}|$ where $\vec x = x \hat{\vec x_0}$ is some arbitrary vector far away from the origin and $\vec x_0$ is the unit vector that points in that direction and $\vec R_{\vec n}$ is just a fixed vector from the origin. If we consider that $\frac{|\vec R_{\vec n}|}{x}<<1$. How does one expand $|\vec x - \vec R_{\vec n}|$ ?
I have never expanded such a thing, which contains vectors.

What do you mean by expandin the distance from a vector $\vec{x}$  to a fixed vector $\vec{R}$ ?  If $R<a x$, say, for some $0<a<1$ then  $$|\vec{x}-\vec{R}|\geq ||\vec{x}|-|\vec{R}||\geq (1-a) x.$$

Write explicitly the absolute value:
$$|\vec x -\vec R|=\sqrt{(\vec x-\vec R)\cdot(\vec x-\vec R)}$$
Here $\cdot$ is the scalar product. Expanding the parenthesis, you get
$$|\vec x -\vec R|=\sqrt{|\vec x|^2-2\vec x\cdot \vec R+|\vec R|^2}$$
We can neglect the last term since $R<<x$ then use the approximation $\sqrt{1-y}\approx1-\frac y2$, so
$$|\vec x -\vec R|\approx|x|\sqrt{1-\frac{2\vec x\cdot\vec R}{|x|^2}}\\\approx|x|\left(1-\frac{\vec x\cdot \vec R}{|x|^2}\right)=|x|-\hat {x_0}\cdot \vec R$$
